# Get array of items from Firebase snapshot

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get an array of items from my Firebase database, using a snapshot generated on page load. I've added the value of each object to an array, and now I'm trying to push an item from each object into another array with a for loop.

But when I create the second array, there are more items in it than there are objects in the snapshot.

I'm wondering how I can get around this. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Code:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/scenes/' + projId).orderByChild('wordcount');
ref.once('value',function(snap) {
    snap.forEach(function(item) {
        var itemVal = item.val();
        keys.push(itemVal);
        for (i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            counts.push(keys[i].wordcount);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you create/initialize `keys`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I initialize keys and counts as empty arrays before this chunk of code.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on from the current snippet. Can you reproduce the problem in a jsbin/jsfiddle?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each time you add something to keys you loop over them all again. You should probably move it outside your forEach:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/scenes/' + projId).orderByChild('wordcount');
ref.once('value',function(snap) {
    snap.forEach(function(item) {
        var itemVal = item.val();
        keys.push(itemVal);
    });
    for (i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        counts.push(keys[i].wordcount);
    }   
});
```

Comment: I love you right now.  Spent way to long trying to figure something similar out. So simple, not sure why I couldn't think of this :(

Comment: for some reason, I cannot iterate firebase snapshots at all. Did something major change in firebase recently? I copied an pasted your code and still get the same error: Argument of type '(item: DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: DataSnapshot) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Answer (score 8):

You can just use `lodash _.toArray()`

`_.toArray(snapshot.val())` will convert your object into an array of objects.

[Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#toArray)

Comment: using your solution I got this error with firebase 5.3.1: snapshot.val is not a function

Answer (score 1):

@mike axle: Just add return true inside forEach. It works for me... ;)

Comment: Actually I needed to use `return false` as `true` would break the `forEach`.